# How can I do a sleep within the while loop?

Tags: c#, email, error-handling, gmail, sleep

I am trying to send email every 30 minutes. within a while loop.

```cs
while (true)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    ReadInput();
    Application.DoEvents();

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    mail.From = new MailAddress("");
    mail.To.Add("");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
    mail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("C://Users//matte//test.txt"));
    mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

I tried an cool-down but the email keeps sending without a sleep. How can I do that. So that the email is sent every 30 minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Sleep function receives amount of time in milliseconds, so it's now waiting right now.

```
public static void Sleep (int millisecondsTimeout);
```

Anyway sleep is not the best option you can use, because it blocks the running process. I would use a datetime when the email is sent and compare `System.DateTime.Now` with this value, so the program continues responding and you can wait just checking if difference between two datetimes is enough time.

```
DateTime LastSend = System.DateTime.Now;

while (true)
{
    if (LastSend.AddMinutes(30) > System.DateTime.Now)
        continue;
    ... your process ...
    LastSend = System.DateTime.Now;
}
```

Hope it helps!